# Dumping Beam-scores to an HDF File

Tags: returnn

I have a translation model (TM), which synthesizes its hypotheses using beam-search. For analysis purposes, I would like to study all hypotheses in each beam emitted by the TM’s [`ChoiceLayer`](https://returnn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layer_reference/recurrent.html?highlight=ChoiceLayer#returnn.tf.layers.rec.ChoiceLayer). I’m able to fetch the hypotheses for each input sequence from the TM’s `ChoiceLayer` and write it to my file system, using the [`HDFDumpLayer`](https://returnn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layer_reference/utility.html?highlight=HDFDumpLayer#hdfdumplayer):

```py
'__SEARCH_dump_beam__': {
    'class': 'hdf_dump',
    'from': ['output'],
    'filename': "<my-path>/beams.hdf",
    'is_output_layer': True
}
```

But beside the hypotheses, I would also like to store the score of each hypothesis. I’m able to fetch the beam scores from the `ChoiceLayer` using a [`ChoiceGetBeamScoresLayer`](https://returnn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layer_reference/recurrent.html?highlight=choicegetbeam#choice-get-beam-scores-layer), but I was not able to dump the scores using an `HDFDumpLayer`:

```py
'get_scores': {'class': 'choice_get_beam_scores', 'from': ['output']},
'__SEARCH_dump_scores__': {
    'class': 'hdf_dump',
    'from': ['get_scores'],
    'filename': "<my-path>/beam_scores.hdf",
    'is_output_layer': True
}
```

Running the config like likes this, makes RETURNN complain about the `ChoiceGetBeamScoresLayer` `output` not having a time axis:

```sh
Exception creating layer root/'__SEARCH_dump_scores__' of class HDFDumpLayer with opts:
{'filename': '<my-path>/beam_scores.hdf',
 'is_output_layer': True,
 'name': '__SEARCH_dump_scores__',
 'network': <TFNetwork 'root' train=False search>,
 'output': Data(name='__SEARCH_dump_scores___output', shape=(), time_dim_axis=None, beam=SearchBeam(name='output/output', beam_size=12, dependency=SearchBeam(name='output/prev:output', beam_size=12)), batch_shape_meta=[B]),
 'sources': [<ChoiceGetBeamScoresLayer 'get_scores' out_type=Data(shape=(), time_dim_axis=None, beam=SearchBeam(name='output/output', beam_size=12, dependency=SearchBeam(name='output/prev:output', beam_size=12)), batch_shape_meta=[B])>]}
Unhandled exception <class 'AssertionError'> in thread <_MainThread(MainThread, started 139964674299648)>, proc 31228.

...

File "<...>/returnn/repository/returnn/tf/layers/basic.py", line 6226, in __init__
    line: assert self.sources[0].output.have_time_axis()
    locals:
      self = <local> <HDFDumpLayer '__SEARCH_dump_scores__' out_type=Data(shape=(), time_dim_axis=None, beam=SearchBeam(name='output/output', beam_size=12, dependency=SearchBeam(name='output/prev:output', beam_size=12)), batch_shape_meta=[B])>
      self.sources = <local> [<ChoiceGetBeamScoresLayer 'get_scores' out_type=Data(shape=(), time_dim_axis=None, beam=SearchBeam(name='output/output', beam_size=12, dependency=SearchBeam(name='output/prev:output', beam_size=12)), batch_shape_meta=[B])>]
      output = <not found>
      output.have_time_axis = <not found>
AssertionError
```

I tried to alter the shape of the score data using [`ExpandDimsLayer`](https://returnn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layer_reference/shape.html#expand-dimensions-layer) and [`EvalLayer`](https://returnn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layer_reference/custom.html?highlight=EvalLayer#returnn.tf.layers.basic.EvalLayer), with several different configurations, but those all lead to different errors.
I’m sure I am not the first person trying to dump beam scores. Can anybody tell me, how to do that properly?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question:

The `HDFDumpLayer` `assert` you are hitting is simply due to the fact that this is not implemented yet (support of dumping data without time axis).
You can create a pull request and add this support for `HDFDumpLayer`.

If you just want to dump this information in any way, not necessarily via `HDFDumpLayer`, there are a couple of other options:

- With `task="search"`, as the `search_output_layer`, just select the layer which still includes the beam information, i.e. not after a `DecideLayer`.
  That will simply dump all hypotheses including their beam scores.
- Use a custom `EvalLayer` and dump it in whatever way you want.